# If Sequentially closed then closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is sequentially closed then it is closed.

I'm trying to prove this directly.
Since $A$ is sequentially closed then if $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to a limit $a$, then $a \in A$.

$$A'=\{x : x \text{ is an accumulation point of } A\}$$

I want to use the fact that a closed set contains all of its accumulation/limiting points to finish this proof but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that.

If I let $b \in A'$ then would it be enough to show that $b \in A$ ?

Comment: So, you want to show that every accumulation point is in fact the limit of a sequence in $A$, right? Fix an accumulation point $x_0 \in A'$ and consider $\{(x_0 - 1/n, x_0+1/n) : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Each of these sets must intersect $A$, so use that to produce a sequence in $A$ converging to $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b \in A'$, it is indeed enoough to show that $b \in A$. Now, for every $n$ consider $(b - \frac{1}{n}, b+ \frac{1}{n})$. This contains some point in $A$ (even some point not equal to $b$, but that we don't need), call it $a_n$.

Then show that $a_n \rightarrow b$, and then use that $A$ is sequentially closed.